# UIDocument saveToURL deletes original file

Tags: uikit, uidocument

I'm trying to use `-[UIDocument saveToURL:(NSURL *)url forSaveOperation:(UIDocumentSaveOperation)saveOperation completionHandler:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL success))completionHandler]` to save a duplicate at a new URL, however the original file `-[UIDocument fileURL]` is deleted when doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, but it seems to be intend. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Here is the Hopper disassembly of iOS 15.2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, UIDocument does that. It's a pain.

If you want to save a UIDocument to a new URL without losing the original, you can do it with a function like this:

```
func saveDocument(_ document: UIDocument, asCopyTo url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    let oldUrl = document.fileURL
    document.save(to: url, for: .forOverwriting) { success in
        if success {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: oldUrl)
            } catch let error {
                completion(false, error)
            }
        }
        completion(success, nil)
    }
}
```

This first saves the existing document at its new url, updating the `fileURL` so that the `UIDocument` object remains current and doesn't keep on saving over the old file. Once that's done, and assuming it succeeds, we use `FileManager` to copy the new file's data back to its original location.

It might seem weird to delete and recreate the file at its original location, and I agree that `UIDocument` is a pretty horrible creation, but this does at least save you from having to reload the document from the file system to maintain the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UIDocument subclass, add this to the subclass and call it instead of the normal `save(to:for:)`. If there's an existing document in the target location, this moves it to a tmp location, increments a number after the name until it finds an unused one, saves the document, and finally restores the original from the tmp location.

```
    func saveRenamingExistingFileIfNecessary(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool)->()) {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let targetDir = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
        var tmpURL: URL?
        let originalURL = fileURL
        var workingFilename = fileURL.lastPathComponent
        var workingURL = fileURL
        
        if fm.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            tmpURL = targetDir.appendingPathComponent("tmp.data")
            do {
                try? fm.removeItem(at: tmpURL!)
                try fm.copyItem(at: fileURL, to: tmpURL!)
            } catch {
                print("*** save error: \(error)")
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }

            let filenameWithoutExtension = ((fileURL.lastPathComponent as NSString).deletingPathExtension as String)
            let fileExtension = fileURL.pathExtension
            var fileCounter = 2
            while fm.fileExists(atPath: workingURL.path) {
                workingFilename = "\(filenameWithoutExtension) \(fileCounter).\(fileExtension)"
                workingURL = targetDir.appendingPathComponent(workingFilename, isDirectory: false)
                fileCounter += 1
            }
        }
        
        save(to: workingURL, for: .forCreating) { success in
            if success {
                if let tmpURL {
                    do {
                        try fm.copyItem(at: tmpURL, to: originalURL)
                        try fm.removeItem(at: tmpURL)
                    } catch {
                        print("*** save error: \(error)")
                        completionHandler(false)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            completionHandler(success)
        }
    }
```